# Watching a specific member in objects of an array in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of objects, something like:

```
$scope.arr = [{firstName: 'foo', lastName: 'bar'}, {firstName: 'john', lastName: 'doe'}]
```

I want to use `$scope.$watch` to watch only the firstName member in the array items. Something like `$scope.$watch('arr[*].firstName', ... )` . Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could simply have the following function in your scope:

```
$scope.getFirstNames = function() {
    return $scope.arr.map(function(element) {
        return element.firstName;
    });
}
```

And then use

```
$scope.$watch('getFirstNames()', ...
```

Comment: I suspect that this will actually trigger the watcher _every_ `$digest` loop since the `.map` will produce a new array reference every time.

Comment: Not if the third argument to $watch (`objectEquality`) is set to true